# how to pass parameters to listener in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I registered `LogConnectionFailed` like this:

```
protected $listen = [
    Registered::class => [
        SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
    ],
    'Illuminate\Http\Client\Events\ConnectionFailed' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogConnectionFailed',
    ],
];
```

The ConnectionFailed event is fired if no response is received for a given request.

```
my class {

  public function send() {

    $response = Http::get('http://example.com');

  }

}
```

I need to The name of the class and the method in which this happened and duration time call http client  in LogConnectionFailed class.

Comment: You can have some hacks with `debug_backtrace()`  and filter its output to match with your desired classes.

Comment: I have multi class and method that call http client. i need to name of class and method. how to get response time? what is best practice for add log in database. Do i register macro or make custom class for call http request and call this class in my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible through normal parameter passing, so I utilized PHP native function `debug_backtrace()` and hacked through it.

The logic is that when the listener wants to handle the event, we get the callback trace and filter through the call stack frames until we find one of our watching location.

The code is this:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Http\Client\Events\ConnectionFailed;

class LogConnectionFailed
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function handle(ConnectionFailed $event)
    {
        $backtraceCollection = Collect(debug_backtrace());
        $callerClass = $backtraceCollection->first(function($value, $key) use ($event){
            $class = $value['class'] ?? '';

            return $this->classIsWatched($class);
        });

        if ($callerClass) {
            // Store in DB or do some other stuff.
            dd([
                'class'    => $callerClass['class'],
                'function' => $callerClass['function'],
                'line'     => $callerClass['line'],
            ]);
        } else {
            dd("should skip. Not Watching classes.");
        }
    }

    private function classIsWatched(string $className): bool
    {
        return Str::is(
            ['App\Http\Controllers\*', 'App\MyClass'],
            $className
        );
    }
}
```

Here take note at the array inside the function `classIsWatched`:

```php
['App\Http\Controllers\*', 'App\MyClass']
```

These are the classes or directories we will watch, which means if the `ConnectionFailed` due to some calls from these classes, they will be captured, else they will be skipped. This gives you the flexibility to just filter out and watch certain locations inside your application.

Note that we can also use wildcards `*` for simplifying the path inclusions. For example `App\Http\Controllers\Api\EventController` is watched too.

For example if I have this class inside the `App` path:

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class MyClass
{
    public static function callEvent()
    {
        $response = Http::get('http://example.com');
    }
}
```

due to any reason if a `ConnectionFailed` event dispatches, the output of handle method will be:

```
array:3 [▼
  "class" => "App\MyClass"
  "function" => "callEvent"
  "line" => 11
]
```

this will give you the **class name**, **function name** and even the **line** which event was raised there. You can simply replace the `dd()` inside the `handle` method of the listener and do what you want to do with the data.

About the Http Call duration, no accurate solution comes to my mind, but you can have a rough estimation using this approach:

```php
dd(microtime(true) - LARAVEL_START);
```

add the above code inside the `handle` method too, and this gives you the time difference from the moment that the application started and till you got this point (Http request failed and you got inside this listener).